# How to pass std input while logging into remote server through script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh, bashrc

While logging into my remote server it expects a user input, it's bash_profile is modified in such a way.

```
[nikhil]$ cat .bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
read -p "enter your name " Name
echo $Name
```

How can i login into this remote server using ssh and pass that input through script.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide information about what you tried and what it did or did not do.

Answer (score 0):

Install `expect`:

```
apt-get install expect
```

Run following script:

```
$ expect <<EOF
set timeout -1

spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" root@server

expect "root@server's password:"
send -- "12345678PASSWORD\r"
expect "enter your name "
send -- "susan\r"
expect "root@server"
send -- "echo $$\r"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
EOF
```

Adapt following:

- `root@server` with your actual server connection parameters
- obviously the password
- the name you want to provide to the script inside `.bash_profile` on the target server
- the actual command you want to run on the target server (instead of `echo $$`)